# Определение версии ОС Windows удалённого сотрудника при VPN подключении и отсечка обладателей "не истинных" версий ОС

Tags: windows, vpn

Есть ли программные средства, которые позволяют определять версию ОС Windows рабочего ПК сотрудника, который по VPN удалённо подключается к офисным ПК и блокировать тех, у кого "старые" версии ОС?
На англоязычных ресурсах нашёл только информацию по FortiGate. В идеале - это должна быть программа, где просто в настройках указывается предпочтение по ОС. Или ПО, в которое можно подгрузить свои самописные скрипты проверки.

Comment: "подгрузить свои самописные скрипты проверки". Есть встречный вопрос: кто их будет грузить, на основании каких правил, политик? Получается, если удаленный клиент включен в систему управления сетью: например Active Directory, то админ может настроить и ожидать (предсказать ) нужное ответное поведение клиента сети. В противном же случае, нужно устанавливать специфичного клиента. Есть, конечно же, ещё вариант детектить удаленного клиента - гуглите **OS Fingerprinting**. Но, мне кажется, это неверный подход, который может лишь дополнить основные решения по безопасности.

Comment: Благодарю за вопрос и комментарий.
По "подгрузке самописных скриптов проверки" - в идеале, это должно быть ПО, которое устанавливается на наш VPN-сервер. Если в нём нет настроек вида "не пускать в сеть сотрудников с ОС ниже Windows 10", то было бы здорово, если бы я сам мог загрузить в это чудо-ПО свой скрипт, который проверял бы версию ОС Windows клиента. В упомянутом ранее FortiGate настройка проверки актуальности ОС есть, но и цена всего этого хозяйства велика, поэтому ищу альтернативы

Comment: Напишите свой скрипт, который будет проверять клиент на соответствие требованиям. При соответствии устанавливать сертификат удаленного VPN-сервера, либо сервера авторизации в центр доверенных сертификатов ОС. Либо пусть скрипт генерирует пользовательские сертификаты после проверки. В общем, какие авторизационные данные будет генерировать скрипт, решайте сами. А вот дальше отдайте скрипт пользователям: кому надо подключаться, тот пусть его и запускает.